# Set typeface menu item actionBar appcompat v7

Tags: android-actionbar, typeface, android-appcompat

I want to change the font of the items menu on an acrionBar.

I'm using appcompat v7 lib to use ActionBar on devices whose Android version is less than 11.

If I change fonts using SpannableString in 'onCreateOptionsMenu()', it works, but in many devices app crashes when you click on item.

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new GTypefaceSpan(context, typefaceName), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
item.setTitle(s);
```

'GTypefaceSpan' is a custom Class to set the font (it works).

I've tried using TextView instead of the item (something like this pseudocode):

```
TextView tVItem1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item1);
tVItem1.set...
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(null, tVItem1);
```

But it crashes directly the app.